# Make draft posts visible for administrators only

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Trying to make a draft post visible to admins only .(when the admin visits the post page it should display the post even if its not published )

I tried to  create a middle-ware :

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $post = Post::findBySlugOrFail($request->slug);
        if ($post->status == "draft") {
            abort(404);
        } elseif (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasAnyRole(['Administrator'])) {

            return $next($request);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

I have `status` column in my `posts` table.

It always shows `404` not found.

Am i doing it wrong ?

Any idea how can this be done ?

Comment: You're checking status first and aborting before the check for admin happens. You need some nested statements or chained conditions (`if(...){ if(...){ ... } }` or `if(... AND ...)`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing you must do is to check the user status if the user status is administrator and post status is draft so you must return to next request from your middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $post = Post::findBySlugOrFail($request->slug);
        // first you must check if the user is administrator and the post status is draft
        if ($post->status == "draft"  && !auth()->user()->hasAnyRole(['Administrator'])) {
            abort(404);
        } elseif (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasAnyRole(['Administrator'])) {

            return $next($request);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the post is a draft the first part of your if statement is always true, which is why it then returns a 404 100% of the time. It's never getting to the step where it checks if the user is an administrator. Try this instead

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $post = Post::findBySlugOrFail($request->slug);
    if ($post->status == "draft" && auth()->check() && !auth()->user()->hasAnyRole(['Administrator']))) {
        abort(404);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

This first checks to see if the post is a draft, if it's not then it shows the next request. If it is, it checks to see if the user is logged in and if they are NOT an administrator. If that is the case, it returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do things in the right order

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $post = Post::findBySlugOrFail($request->slug);
    if ($post->status == "draft" &&
        auth()->check()          && 
        auth()->user()->hasAnyRole(['Administrator'])) 
    {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }

}
```